# How can I distribute tasks to assignees with varying capacities

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have list of tasks and I want to automatically assign them between a list of staff members.

Each staff member has a different capacity for how many tasks they can do and I want the automatic allocation of tasks to take into account each staff member's max capacity.

I also want the allocation to take into account the order in which staff members are listed to facilitate task allocation on a first-come-first-served basis.

So far I've been able to *evenly* distribute the tasks, and where tasks cannot be evenly distributed, have prioritised staff members by order, however, I've not been able to take max capacity into account.

Here is a link to my Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pr87yOdt0MS7rJ09NKqDMjwNi_UGi5reqqLGQjR8TuY/edit?usp=sharing

Note: the cells containing formulas have been highlighted in Cyan for easy reference.

**Do you know how to solve this problem?**

Comment: While a link to an external resource might be helpful, as questions on this site should be self-contained, please [edit] the question to describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet and to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this: I first created a kind of "rounds" finding in each number of tasks assigned who would be able to work resulting in a table like this:

[image]

Then I wrapped it in a query selecting Col2 (only the names), where they weren't empty, and limiting the amount to the count of tasks in E2:E:

[image]

Let me know if this works for you, of this is what you meant. Here you have the formula in F2:

```
=QUERY(LAMBDA(name,num,qt,MAKEARRAY(qt*MAX(num),2,LAMBDA(r,c,LAMBDA(round,ind,IF(c=1,round,IF(INDEX(num,ind,1)>=round,INDEX(name,ind),"")))(ROUNDUP(r/qt,0),MOD(r-1,qt)+1))))(FILTER(Availability!A2:A,Availability!A2:A<>""),FILTER(Availability!C2:C, Availability!A2:A<>""),COUNTA(FILTER(Availability!A2:A,Availability!A2:A<>""))),"Select Col2 where Col2 <>'' limit "&COUNTA(E2:E))
```

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you so much for the quick response.